# How to make a pair of six-sided dice whose sum is always a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, dice

In other words, how can I find two sets of six distinct integers $a_1, \dots, a_6 \in \Bbb Z$ and $b_1, \dots, b_6 \in \Bbb Z$ such that $a_i+b_j$ is prime for any $i, j \in \{1, \dots, 6\}$?

Comment: I've edited your notation into a form that will make answers easier to write. Please edit again if I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: By [Green-Tao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem) a solution exists. There is an arithmetic progression of eleven primes $a+nd, n=0,1,\ldots,10$. Label the first dice $a+kd, k=0,1,2,\ldots,5$, and the second with $jd, j=0,1,2,\ldots,5$. I think a method for finding a smaller solution exists :-)

Comment: Adding the [tag:number-theory] tag back. This is vaguely connected to relatively non-trivial problems in number theory even though a computer search is likely to produce good solutions. Sorry about the see-saw.

Comment: Where does this question come from? Did you come up with it yourself of is there are source? If the former, what is the motivation?

Comment: @quid: While your question is valid and I hope the OP answers it, this is certainly an interesting problem in recreational mathematics that the OP _could_ plausibly have come up with on their own. Hopefully the motivation is clearer now that I've restored (and slightly copyedited) the original title.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen  I agree that in this case the dice-angle might be relevant, and it was likely a good idea to restore it while keeping also the mathematical clarifications.

Comment: Can somebody explain why this question has three close votes? It looks like a perfectly good question to me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  why did you delete your answer.  I think it is a good one

Comment: Time to get rid of rules that require this question should be closed. Wake up moderators.

Comment: @RossMillikan This is certainly a PSQ, so I quite understand those who want this thread to go away. I do think that the PSQ-policy is mostly targeting homework help seekers. Yet, I would also appreciate it if the asker would reply to quid's question. I also think that Empy2's answer is better than mine: it produces smaller primes, and is something somebody might find with a sensible search. My answer is relying on the OEIS.

Comment: @TonyK I don't get why you reopened the question. This question is very poor: **1)** It states the problem, without *any effort whatsoever*. **2)** There are already comments (such as quid's) asking OP for further details, but the OP has not provided any response despite him being active for the past few days (last seen 20 hours ago). **3)** Leaving this question open will simply encourage future poor questions being allowed. Therefore, I advocate for the closure (through: *off-topic*, as it is *missing context*) and deletion of this question.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: I voted to reopen because I like the question and some of the answers. (And I think you should chill out a little.)

Comment: "Liking" a question is subjective. Close reasons are objective. @TonyK

Comment: Redeleting my answer and voting to close as the asker is non-responsive. Apparently they have abandoned this question, and have come back for more help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3316882/11619). This is so not ok.

Answer (score 5):

All the answers here are much larger than necessary. I wrote a computer program to find a set of numbers such that the largest number used is as small as possible. An optimal solution is:

$$A = \{5, 13, 17, 47, 73, 83\}$$
$$B = \{0, 6, 24, 54, 66, 84\}$$

However this has duplicate possible rolls. If this is unacceptable and each combination of rolls must be distinct an optimal solution is:

$$A = \{0, 26, 56, 96, 140, 180\}$$
$$B = \{11, 17, 71, 83, 137, 173\}$$

Answer (score 2):

A 12-term arithmetic progression of primes exists by Green-Tao (as stated in comments). Richard K. Guy, 1994 gives one as $23143 + 30030k$. So we can find two sets $A, B$:

$$A=\lbrace{23143, 53173, 83203, 113233, 143263, 173293\rbrace}$$

$$B=\lbrace{30030, 60060, 90090, 120120, 150150, 180180\rbrace}$$

Comment: As $23143$ is prime you can replace $180180$ with $0$ on $B$ to get a smaller solution

Answer (score 0):

We can have $$A=\{1,7,13,17,19,23\} \\
B=\{2670,24090,198810,560220,603900,663960\}$$
I just wrote a program to check multiples of $30$ for the second die that would work with the first using the base 2 Fermat test.  I then checked them by hand in Alpha, which disqualified $126210$ because $126217$ is a 2-pseudoprime.  This produces $36$ distinct prime numbers from the rolls.